# rsync mkdir failed permission denied

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm running PuTTy ssh on windows in the hope to copy a file from a remote server. 
The command I used is below:

```
rsync -avz user@server:/home/user/imitate/tool /home/tool
```

But I received the error:

```
rsync: mkdir "/home/tool" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
```

I'm totally new to this and I have no idea what is happening. So I logged into an account on a remote server using ssh, and want to copy files from that remote server to the laptop I'm using. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot write to `/home/tool` locally on your windows box. either run the command with more privileges or download to another directories where you have write permissions.

Comment: ps: did you use putty to connect to the remote server and are you running the command over there? if this is the case you are doing it wrong and we'd need to backtrack much further. generally you might be off better using winscp or filezilla for simple manual file downloads over sftp.